# Partially visible TreeNodes in java swing

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I am making a directory viewer with the help of JTree in java.swing The problem with the GUI is that the nodes are partially visible and are visible only after I exapand the child nodes

[Before Expanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPMbH.png)

[After Expanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ip97g.png)

Here is the code to the above

```
public class ProjectStructure extends JPanel{
private JTree directory;

public ProjectStructure() {
    setLayout(new BoxLayout(this,BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    Dimension size = getPreferredSize();
    size.width = 250;
    setPreferredSize(size);

    setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Explorer"));
}

void displayFilesInDirectory(File file){
    DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(file.getName());
    generateTreeView(file, root);

    directory = new JTree(root);
    directory.setVisible(true);
    add(directory);
}

private void generateTreeView(File rootFile, DefaultMutableTreeNode parent) {
    File[] files = rootFile.listFiles();

    if (files != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(files[i].getName());
            parent.add(node);
            if (files[i].isDirectory()) {
                generateTreeView(files[i], node);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Also can I make the JPanel resizable with a drag and drop feature?

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. Please [edit] the question to add 4 space chars ahead of the closing `}` at the end of the code. 3) See the [File Browser GUI](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/4446/7784) for tips. 4) `setPreferredSize(size);` See..

Comment: ..  [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) 5) Put the tree in a `JScrollPane`. 6) Don't extend `JPanel`, just use an instance of a standard panel. 7) `directory.setVisible(true);` this is usually not necessary for anything but top level containers like `JFrame` or `JDialog`, A component becomes visible if it is added to a TLC that is set visible.